# Not able to parse nested Json array in PHP while print_r function is printing all values properly

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json array string. Though print_r prints all the values properly but while fetching the records I failed.

I must be doing something very terribly wrong. Could you please help to correct it.

So here is my code

```
<?
  $str ='
  { 
   "tenant_view_details": [ 
   { 
    "status":"S", 
    "tenant_general":[
    {"tenant_id":"6003","code":"ICI001","type":"BANK","category":"SM","gstn":"IWSDFS7372","pan":"KSAH9876AS","cin":"ASHED456","name":"ICICI Bank","address_line_1":"23, Hertz Plaza, Rajiv Chowk","address_line_2":" ","address_city":"New Delhi","address_distict ":"New Delhi","address_state ":"DL","address_state_code ":"07","address_pin ":"119923","contact_name ":"contact_name","contact_phone ":"1234567890","contact_std_code ":"11","contact_landline ":"1234567890","contact_email_id ":"contact@email.com"} ], 
    "tenant_bank": [ 
    { "bank_name ":"xyz","bank_account_no ":"12345","account_type ":"abc","ifsc_code ":"xx123","address_line_1 ":"qwer","address_line_2         ":"23","address_city ":"abc","address_district ":"xyz","address_state_name ":"asd","address_state_code ":"02","address_pin ":"123456" } ], 
    "tenant_agreement": [ 
    { "category ":"OM","tenancy_type ":"EXT","echarge_type ":"FIX","total_tenancy_value ":"32900.00","energy_charge_value ":"16543.00","rev_share_pct ":"0.05","start_dt":"10-1-2018","end_dt":"31-12-2020","attachment_path ":"na","change_value ":"na","latest_flag ":"Y","w_status ":"20","status ":"ACT"} ],
    "tenant_sites": [ 
    {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1020","tn_site_code":"UPWMORA00069473","tn_site_name":"Deendayal Nagar","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"MAST","site_type":"ID","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"}, {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1019","tn_site_code":"UPWGHAZ00069467","tn_site_name":"DJ College Newari Road, Modina","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"MAST","site_type":"ID","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"}, {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1018","tn_site_code":"UPWMORA00069464","tn_site_name":"Bazar Makhbra","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"RTT","site_type":"OD","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"}, {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1016","tn_site_code":"UPWGHAZ00069454","tn_site_name":"Hoshdarpur Garhi","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"RTT","site_type":"OD","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"}, {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1011","tn_site_code":"UPWMUZN00069430","tn_site_name":"Sikanderpur","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"RTT","site_type":"ID","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"}, {"tenant_id":"6003","site_master_id":"1008","tn_site_code":"UPWALIG00069299","tn_site_name":"Mukund Vihar","tn_cluster":"CLUSTER-03","circle_code":"UW","tower_type":"RTT","site_type":"","tenancy_type":"EXT","echarge_type":"FIX","primary_tenant":"N","latest_flag ":"Y"} ]
 }
 ]
}
';
$dataset = json_decode($str, true);
//print_r ($dataset);

foreach ($dataset['tenant_view_details'] as $newdata) {
 $general = $newdata['tenant_general'];
 $bank = $newdata['tenant_bank'];
 $agreement = $newdata['tenant_agreement'];
 $sites = $newdata['tenant_sites'];
}
//prinitng data
echo "<br/>";
print_r($general);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($bank);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($agreement);
 echo "<br/>";

foreach($general as $general_data){
 (isset($general_data['tenant_id']) && !empty($general_data['tenant_id']))? $tenant_id=$general_data['tenant_id'] : $tenant_id="not set";
 echo "<br/>tenant_id::" . $tenant_id;
}

foreach($bank as $bank_data){
 (isset($bank_data['bank_name']) && !empty($bank_data['bank_name']))? $bank_name=$bank_data['bank_name'] : $bank_name="not set";     
 echo "<br/>bank_name:" . $bank_data['bank_name'];
}
foreach($agreement as $agreement_data){
 (isset($agreement_data['category']) && !empty($agreement_data['category']))? $category=$agreement_data['category'] : $category="not set";
 (isset($agreement_data['tenancy_type']) && !empty($agreement_data['tenancy_type']))? $tenancy_type=$agreement_data['tenancy_type'] : $tenancy_type="not set";
 (isset($agreement_data['echarge_type']) && !empty($agreement_data['echarge_type']))? $echarge_type=$agreement_data['echarge_type'] : $echarge_type="not set";
 echo "<br/>category:" . $category;
 echo "<br/>tenancy_type:" . $tenancy_type;
 echo "<br/>echarge_type:" . $echarge_type;
}
?>
```

Comment: typo: `"tenant_bank": [   { "bank_name "` Notice the trailing space

Comment: Use xdebug + a IDE with integrated debugging client like Netbeans, Eclipse, PhpStorm.

Comment: How was the JSON generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `$bank` and `$category` arrays, all the keys have trailing spaces on them. If you change the references to include those spaces, your code works fine. See https://3v4l.org/GX5iC

Alternatively you can trim the array keys, using something like this code inside your `foreach` loops:

```
$bank_keys = array_map('trim', array_keys($bank_data));
$bank_data = array_combine($bank_keys, array_values($bank_data));
```

You could also create a recursive function to trim the entire `$dataset` value. For example:

```
function trim_keys($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "trimming key '$key' to '" . trim($key) . "'\n";
        unset($array[$key]);
        $array[trim($key)] = $value;
        if (is_array($value))
            $array[trim($key)] = trim_keys($value);
        else
            $array[trim($key)] = $value;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Then, by using

```
$dataset = trim_keys($dataset);
```

Your code will work fine. [Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/6OZcv)

Comment: As mentioned in comments it's a typo. Question should be voted to close instead of being answered since there is no advantage to others looking for solutions of their problems.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone it's not really a typo - the data is coming to OP like that. Some of the keys have extra spaces, some don't. That's why I've offered a solution which trims the spaces from the keys so that OP doesn't have to figure them all out individually.